# Facebook Like button - Yahoo Implementation

Tags: facebook, yahoo, facebook-like

Could someone tell me how this could be done?

```
http://l.yimg.com/p/social_buttons/facebook-share-iframe.php?u=http://www.lifehacker.com
```

This is basically a Facebook share button that is used by Yahoo in one of their blogs. The reason I am interested in this is because 
1. it is very fast.
2. Has very few requests to facebook servers, unlink the Facebook iframe like button.

I currently use the Facebook Iframe button and it makes lot of requests to the fbcdn servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're asking about manually tacking the count on the end of a plain graphic:
`http://l.yimg.com/p/social_buttons/facebook-share-iframe.php`

If so, what you're talking about is [generating a graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901201/create-a-dynamic-png-image-using-php) (ie: png, but you can do jog, as well() and maybe using an [fb api](http://developers.facebook.com/) to get at the current count, if you're not tracking it yourself. Using the API isn't trivial to set up or use, but after you get the pieces in place, fairly intuitive to use.

If you're talking about just doing a different button, I'd advise against it. That's just how that facebook feature works. It's great because it out of the box, though it does have requests to fb servers for it to work.