# Creating png image using PHP

Tags: php, image, png

Let's say I have a table of 480.000 values, and these values are between -1 to 10. -1 means transparency and 0 to 10 means a color.

Can I create a PNG image using PHP? I mean get every value (one by one) set pixel color or transparent pixels and export a PNG image[800x600] ?

I don't need code (would be nice tho), I just need to know if it's possible, and I will start the research. If it's not using PHP, then how is it possible? Another language-technology ? P.S. I want to program a server (CGI) for this job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901201/create-a-dynamic-png-image-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this. I think this best documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php