# Set the favicon on a non HTML page

Tags: php, favicon

I'm using PHP to display an image (dynamically returning a binary blob with a mime type of `image/png` for example) so that means I can't use the typical method for changing the favicon (`link` tags).

The HTML solution is this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Is there a way I can set the favicon in PHP for a non HTML document?

Comment: `I'm using PHP right now to display an image so that means absolutely no HTML is allowed` What does that mean?

Comment: @JohnConde I don't know the best way of explaining it since I'm fairly new to PHP but I did ask a question about it a little while ago so you can understand what I mean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727045/image-as-a-php-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most browsers will default to looking for a favicon in the root directory like so: http://example.com/favicon.ico. You can use this for a favicon for your images.

If you want different favicons for each image, that's simply not possible (browsers provide no mechanism for this). There is a proposed standard for setting favicons via HTTP headers ([RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988)) but it's still a draft and hasn't been implemented by browser vendors.

Comment: So if I were to put say, favicon-a in my root directory and then favicon-b in a subdirectory, would the pages in the subdirectory take favicon-a or favicon-b? Because that's how my website is set up right now.

Comment: No, the browser **only** looks in the root directory